# Select specific joined object

Tags: objects

I have an object to which another object has been added.
However, only the first object appears in the outliner.

I'm able to select it using the B key and then trying to catch all vertices of this object, but if the 2 objects were even overlapping, this wouldn't be possible.

Is there a way to select the attached (or the original object) with a shortcut instead of having to select each vertex of it?

[image]

Comment: with L you can select a whole separate mesh, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with L you can select a whole separate mesh

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object while in edit mode, the new mesh gets merged into the current mesh object.

As already answered, pressing <kbd>L</kbd> will select all vertices linked to the vertex under the cursor. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> is similar but it works from the existing selection instead of what is near the cursor.

Once you have selected the vertices you could either use <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them if they were added by mistake, or you can press <kbd>P</kbd>*->Selection* to split the selected verts into an object of its own. In your example you can also skip the selecting and just use <kbd>P</kbd>*->By Loose Parts* to split each non-connected mesh into its own object.